# Firebase Analytics - Custom Event Params not shown in Dashboard

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

We are facing an issue with Firebase Analytics where the custom parameters that we send from custom events are not being shown in Dashboard. We even added Custom Definitions for the custom parameters that we want to track still it is showing within the custom events view.

Any kind of help is really appreciated.

Thanks,